# FindFit only fitting portions of data

Tags: fitting

I'm currently trying to fit some complicated data sets and I am having some luck. The higher temperature data works just fine with `FindFit`.

Unfortunately, however, the lower temperature data refuses to fit, regardless of how close the starting parameters are.

The code is below. You will also need a data set to import, which you can download from [this link to GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6UCaksSu6VaV0cxZF85emxwcFU&usp=sharing).

```
axisFlip = # /. {x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
      MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1], 
     x : (PlotRange -> _) :> x~Reverse~2} &;  
SetDirectory["F:\\IVsandtemplatesdesktop\\IVTD_T793_02_27_2015"];  
filename = "T793_Dark_150_2015-02-26 18-17-09.txt";  
dataimp = Import[filename, "Table"][[11 ;;]];  
jvdata = {Thread[{dataimp[[;; , 1]], 0.001*Abs[dataimp[[;; , 2]]]}]};
jvdata = Select[Table[{jvdata[[1, i, 1]], jvdata[[1, i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[jvdata[[1, ;; , 1]]]}], 
   NumericQ[#[[1]]] && NumericQ[#[[2]]] && #[[2]] != 0 &];
jvdata = Sort[jvdata, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];  
vjdata = Transpose[{Sign[jvdata[[;; , 1]]] jvdata[[;; , 2]], jvdata[[;; , 1]]}];  
vjdataforward = Select[vjdata, #[[2]] > 0 &];  
vjdatareverse = Select[vjdata, #[[2]] < 0 &];  

Clear[Jfunction];  
Jfunction[V_?NumericQ, J01_?NumericQ, A1_?NumericQ, J02_?NumericQ, 
   A2_?NumericQ, Rs_?NumericQ, Rsh_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
   m_?NumericQ] :=
  J /. FindRoot[
    J == Abs[J01 (Exp[A1 (V - Sign[V] J Rs)] - 1)] + 
      Abs[J02 (Exp[A2 (V - Sign[V] J Rs)] - 1)] + 
      k Abs[(V - Sign[V] J Rs)]^m + 
      Abs[(V - Sign[V] J Rs)/Rsh], {J, -5, 4}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxIterations -> 100000];  

Clear[Vfunction];    
Vfunction[J_?NumericQ, J01_?NumericQ, A1_?NumericQ, J02_?NumericQ, 
   A2_?NumericQ, Rs_?NumericQ, Rsh_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
   m_?NumericQ] :=
  V /. FindRoot[
    J == J01 (Exp[A1 (V - J Rs)] - 1) + J02 (Exp[A2 (V - J Rs)] - 1) +
       Sign[J] k Abs[(V - J Rs)]^m + (V - J Rs)/
      Rsh, {V, -3 HeavisideTheta[-J], 3 HeavisideTheta[J]}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxIterations -> 100000];  

T = 150; (* Temperature in Kelvin *)  
q = 1.602176565*10^-19;(*C*)    
kb = 1.3806488*10^-23;(*J/K*)  
J01init = 1.2*^-33;  
A1init = 63;  
J02init = 2.601488095513*^-12;  
A2init = 13.339343747213;  
Rsinit = 4500.0;  
Rshinit = 5.9*^9;  
kinit = 1.5*^-9;  
minit = 2.6;      

Show[
  ListLogLinearPlot[MapAt[Abs[#] &, #, 1] & /@ vjdata, Joined -> True],
  LogLinearPlot[{Vfunction[j, J01init, A1init, J02init, A2init, 
     Rsinit, Rshinit, kinit, minit], 
    Vfunction[-j, J01init, A1init, J02init, A2init, Rsinit, Rshinit, 
     kinit, minit]}, {j, Min[Abs[vjdata[[;; , 1]]]], 
    1.5*Max[Abs[vjdata[[;; , 1]]]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red]]
  ] // axisFlip

fit = Quiet[
  FindFit[vjdata, {Vfunction[j, J01, Abs[A1], J02, Abs[A2], Abs[Rs], 
     Abs[Rsh], Abs[k], Abs[m]]},
   {{J01, J01init}, {A1, A1init}, {J02, J02init}, {A2, A2init}, {Rs, 
     Rsinit}, {Rsh, Rshinit}, {k, kinit}, {m, minit}}, j, 
   MaxIterations -> 10000(*,EvaluationMonitor :> Print[
   "J01:",J01," A1:",A1," J02:",J02," A2:",A2," Rs:",Rs," Rsh:",Rsh,
   " k:",k," m:",m]*)]]
```

Comment: Your notebook includes pages and pages of code. Very few people will have the time and patience to wade through that much code and results to even try to understand what you are trying to do. You want to generate a **minimal working example** instead: add the specific data that is giving your trouble and the code that you are using to attempt the fit directly to your question.

Comment: Haha fair enough. I shall edit and include just one temperature

Comment: Okay so finished editing. For some reason it wouldn't let me keep my link in the topic so I'm adding the shortened notebook and data set link here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6UCaksSu6VaV0cxZF85emxwcFU&usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if you use `Method -> NMinimize`?

Comment: 5 or so minutes in and it still isn't finished evaluating using that method. Not sure it will evaluate it.

Comment: @Anthony The definition of `Jfunction` in your code above seems irrelevant to your current issue, so it should probably be removed for the sake of clarity and readability. Similarly, `jvdata` seems to be unused.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that this is a comment, rather than a proper answer.

Your problem may actually lie within your `Vfunction`, rather than with `FindFit`, but it has been hidden by the fact that you wrapped `FindFit` in `Quiet`, thus suppressing all errors and warnings.

If you add `Method -> NMinimize` to `FindFit` and remove the `Quiet` wrapper, you will receive repeated warnings:

```
fit = FindFit[
  vjdata,
  Vfunction[j, J01, Abs[A1], J02, Abs[A2], Abs[Rs], Abs[Rsh], Abs[k], Abs[m]], 
  {{J01, J01init}, {A1, A1init}, {J02, J02init}, {A2, A2init}, {Rs, Rsinit}, {Rsh, Rshinit}, {k, kinit}, {m, minit}},
  j,
  MaxIterations -> 10, Method -> NMinimize
 ]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100000 iterations. >>

This must come from within your `Vfunction` expression, which is repeatedly evaluated by `FindFit`, since it is the only expression invoked here that has a maximum number of iterations set to 100,000.

This may be due to some "brittleness" in your `Vfunction`, i.e. very strong sensitivity to the input parameters. Since you have a very good idea of what the values of the parameters should be, you may want to try and **restrict the search regions** on those parameters e.g. using constraints.